# How to use loop of for in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I was learning Python,and I know how to use usual loop of `for`,but I can't understand the following codes of `for` loop in python.Please show me a website to learn the details or explain how to use it,thank you very much;

```
def billboard(name, price = 30):
    return sum(price for ch in name)
```

Comment: @vaultah: In this case it's a generator expression and not a list comprehension but the principle remains the same.

Comment: @Matthias: yes, the answer covers generator expressions.

Comment: @vaultah: You're right. I couldn't read so fast ...

Answer (score -2):

```
def billboard(name, price = 30):
    return [price + ch for ch in name]
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Ehh? The code in the question works.